# O que é e para que serve um TLAB?

Tags: java, gerenciamento-de-memória

Recentemente utilizei o Java Mission Control (JMC) para rastrear um *memory leak*.
Ao fazer isso percebi que o JMC reporta alocações de memória dentro e fora de *Thread Local Allocation Buffers* (TLAB).
Em uma busca rápida no Google li que alocações de novos objetos dentro de um TLAB é mais eficientes do que fora.

Mas o que exatamente é um *TLAB*? Como ele torna a alocação de novos objetos mais eficiente? E o que faz a JVM escolher alocar memória dentro ou fora de um TLAB?

Comment: Parte da minha iniciativa para criar perguntas para a comunidade.